# Where can I read the English translated version of some niche light novels?

Tags: resources, light-novel-site

I find some niche anime stories quite interesting, namely, *Nanana's Buried Treasure* and *Dantalian no Shoka*, but I can't find a website where I can read the whole light novels of them. The ones I found all stop abruptly at the middle.

Where can I read the English translated version of those niche light novels?

Comment: Note that this community doesn't support piracy, so only legal sources will be allowed. Questionable sources will be deleted without prejudice.

Comment: For really niche light novels, there's a good chance an English translation doesn't exist; your only recourse would be to hire a translator yourself, or use OCR plus a machine translation.

Comment: What worked for Spice and Wolf was creating a small, hidden community of people pitching in money and then paying an actual translator. The rate at the time was $500 per volume. We got a full translation of Spice and Wolf back in 2013 that way. The official translation only came to that same point three years later.

Answer (score 2):

Baka Tsuki is the only good site I know that has several Light Novel translations. They seem to have some incomplete chapters of [Dantalion no Shoka](https://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Dantalian_no_Shoka).

It is afaik (semi-)legal, in the sense that they stop translating & hosting chapters of licensed LNs. Their [About](https://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Baka-Tsuki:About) page says *Works will be deleted upon request by copyright holders*, and I remember having some series go MIA due to licensing a few years back when I used to be a frequent visitor.

Note that the site itself has fan translations, so it's not officially licensed and the TL quality can vary between series (but has been mostly excellent in my experience).